# if condition not reevaluating on google sheet based off NOW() and time

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell P2 with the NOW() function and formatted to display time.

```
=NOW()
```

I also have another cell with a If condition that evaluates the time from P2 now() compares against a set time 1400 in this case and sets the Cell to be TRUE or FALSE

```
=if(P2<time(14,0,0),TRUE,FALSE)
```

I set the spreadsheet's refresh rate to be every minute.

Before 1400, I was expecting it to set to TRUE
Once the time is past 1400, I was expecting the cell to update to FALSE

This is where I see a problem, the cell doesn't reevaluate the time based off the spreadsheet refresh settings. If I paste in the same formula it'll reevaluate at the new cell to show the expected results.

How can I get the spreadsheet to reevaluate the time based off the NOW() and Time functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOW` is not just a time it is a today's date and now's time. So, you need to subtract `TODAY` from it to get only the time. Date time is a number: date part is the integer-part of a number, time - fractional-part.

One way to drop the date would be to use `MOD(NOW(), 1)`.

```
=IF(MOD(P2, 1) < TIME(14, 0, 0), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Or better leave it as it was and just put `=MOD(NOW(), 1)` in `P2`.

Here is a little demonstartion:

[image]

---

I suggested before to use `NOW() - TODAY()` which looks clear, but I think it could give you more then 24 hours on the edge of a day. So, better not use this method.

Answer (score 0):

try directly:

```
=IF(TIMEVALUE(NOW())<TIMEVALUE(TIME(14, 0, 0)), TRUE)
```

and also set:

[image: 0]

Comment: Hey I’ve tried that and it doesn’t work. 

Can’t seem to directly compare now with time. It’s always false.